# KafkaStreams not shutting down

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

If I create and start a KafkaStream instance, and then in a shutdown hook call .close(), nothing happens - the logging indicates that the one StreamThread that exists has entered a PENDING_SHUTDOWN state, but then just sits like that forever. I've tried everything with no luck - have read the Kafka streams source code to see what it's doing during shutdown but to my eyes the code implies that the StreamThread, if in a running state, will never stop (which can't be right - I've not seen any bugs of this nature filed in the Kafka JIRA).

Here is the pertinent code of my simple KafkaStream (scala) application:

```
val props: Properties = {
  val p = new Properties()
  p.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "test-application")
  p.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092")
  p.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, "1")
 p
}


implicit val produced = Produced.`with`(new StringSerde(), new StringSerde())

val builder: StreamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder()
val in: KStream[String, String] = builder.stream[String, String]("input-topic")

in.map((k,v) =>{ 
         println("Consumed and transforming value")
         (k,s"$v_transformed") 
     }).to("output-topic")

val streams: KafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props)

streams.start()

sys.addShutdownHook(streams.stop())
```

As you can see, it's just reading from one topic, making a tiny change to the value from the consumed record and writing it to another topic.

The stream is started and the application will call stop() when a SIGINT is sent to it.

When I ^C to terminate the process, I see Kafka logging stating that the StreamThread-1 is being transitioned to PENDING_SHUTDOWN and that's as far as it ever gets. It should eventually (within seconds) reach state NOT_RUNNING but it never does, and it continues to output my println statement for every record it's continuing to read from the input-topic.

What am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE: as per suggestion from commenter, i tried calling close() with a timeout of 60 seconds, and just got this eventually, but still no shutdown:-

> [shutdownHook1] INFO  o.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams -
>   stream-client
>   [-]
>   Streams client cannot stop completely within the timeout

Comment: You might hit a deadlock situation and should apply a timeout to `close()` operations. Cf https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5571 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4366

Comment: Thanks Matthias - but i'm just struggling to make it do anything right now - I did try introducing an explicit timeout of 60 seconds just to see what would happen, and all that happened was that it carried on processing stuff for 60 seconds and then logged that it could not transition state within the timeout.

Comment: Not sure atm what the issue could be. What version are you using?

Comment: Version 2.0.0 - I gave up in the end and I am using Alpakka Kafka connector instead - it plays better with Futures anyway and uses full-blown Akka Streams so fits more with what I'm doing.